# How can I store HTML content that is going to be appended in more than one line?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

After getting success in my AJAX response, I need to append HTML content inside a `div`. Usually, I do something like this:

```
$(".parent").append("<div class='child'>Text</div>");
```

This is usually fine, except when I have a massive quantity of content that I need to be appended. For example, I need to append this HTML text inside the parent `div`:

```
<div class="mt-5 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 1</p>
        <i class="some-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 2</p>
        <div>Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can put this text in one line, yes, but it is massively unorganized, confusing and hard to read.

Is there any way to keep the text uncondensed in the `append` function? Or is there another jQuery function that allows me not to use this text in one single line?

I would apreciate any help.

Comment: What does this have to do with ajax? Is the HTML _returned_ from an ajax call?

Comment: To do what you ask (*"keep the text uncondensed"*), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/2181514) - however it (and the *numerous* other duplicates) are a little out of date and you've also asked *is there another [way to do this]* which is succinctly answered below: use `<template>` and clone it.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the following demo that stores html in a template element. The good thing with a template element is that by design it doesn't get rendered to the page.

```js
let $template = $($.find("#template1")[0].innerHTML)

$(".parent").append($template);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">

</div>

<template id="template1">
    <div class="mt-5 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <p>Text example 1</p>
            <i class="some-icon"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <p>Text example 2</p>
            <div>Description</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element to hold the html.

```js
const template1 = document.querySelector("#myTemplate");
document.querySelector(".add").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const elements = template1.content.cloneNode(true);
  document.querySelector(".out").appendChild(elements);
});
```

```css
.out > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<template id="myTemplate">
<div class="mt-5 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 1</p>
        <i class="some-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 2</p>
        <div>Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<button class="add">Add</button>
<div class="out"></div>
```

Other option is to use a string template literal

```js
var myTemplate = `
<div class="mt-5 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 1</p>
        <i class="some-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 2</p>
        <div>Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
`;

document.querySelector(".add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".out").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', myTemplate);
});
```

```css
.out>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button class="add">Add</button>
<div class="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use jQuery in a project I always create a couple of extension functions for this express purpose.

```
function createElement(tag) {
    return $('<' + tag + '>');
}

function createElement(tag, className) {
    return $('<' + tag + '>').addClass(className);
}
```

They might be included in another library that I'm not aware of by default.

But anyway, with these two functions you can turn this:

```
$(".parent").append("<div class="child">Text</div>");
```

Into this:

```
$('.parent').append(createElement('div', 'child').text('Text'));
```

To append something more like this:

```
<div class="mt-5 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 1</p>
        <i class="some-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>Text example 2</p>
        <div>Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might do:

```
$('.appendTarget')
    .append( 
        createElement('div', 'mt-5 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center')
            .append(
                      createElement('div', 'col-md-5')
                           .append(
                                createElement('p').text('My Silly Text'),
                                createElement('i', 'some-icon')
                           ),
                       createElement('div','col-md-5')
                           .append(
                                    createElement('p').text('more text'),
                                    createElement('div').text('Description')
                                  )
                   )
     );
```

Answer (score -2):

Please, do not use jquery if you can.

Show this simple example:

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
const child = document.createElement('li');

// if you need to add css class:
// child.classList.add('item');

child.textContent = 'my first li!';

ul.appendChild(child);
```

✌️

Comment: Would be ok if you actually answered OPs question with vanilla js.